# How to fin the evolution of the mean

Tags: python

I have this following matrix, C, which is a matrix 20x4 containing only 4 possible values (apple, banana, coconut and durian). Each row is one iteration (20 in total). I am trying to write a program that starts by the first row, counts the amount of each fruit and gives me the average. Then should go to the second row and calculate again the average, but this time taking into account both (the first and the second row) and so on. This is what I have been trying but obviously not correct.

Could anyone let me know where I am making a mistake?

```
C = [['durian', 'durian', 'coconut', 'durian'], ['durian', 'apple', 'durian', 'coconut'], ['coconut', 'durian', 'coconut', 'durian'], ['coconut', 'durian', 'banana', 'durian'], ['banana', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana'], ['coconut', 'durian', 'durian', 'coconut'], ['banana', 'durian', 'banana', 'coconut'], ['coconut', 'banana', 'durian', 'coconut'], ['durian', 'banana', 'coconut', 'durian'], ['durian', 'durian', 'durian', 'banana'], ['banana', 'apple', 'coconut', 'banana'], ['coconut', 'coconut', 'coconut', 'durian'], ['banana', 'coconut', 'durian', 'durian'], ['durian', 'durian', 'durian', 'coconut'], ['durian', 'coconut', 'durian', 'durian'], ['banana', 'apple', 'durian', 'durian'], ['durian', 'banana', 'banana', 'durian'], ['coconut', 'durian', 'coconut', 'coconut'], ['apple', 'coconut', 'durian', 'durian'], ['coconut', 'apple', 'coconut', 'banana']]

for i in C[i]:
        Apple=C.count('apple')
        Banana=C.count('banana')
        Coconut=C.count('coconut')
        Durian=C.count('durian')
        Total=len(C)*len(C[0])
        avg_apple=Apple/Total
        avg_banana=Banana/Total
        avg_coconut=Coconut/Total
        avg_durian=Durian/Total
        avg=[avg_apple,avg_banana,avg_coconut,avg_durian]
        average.append(avg)
        apple.append(avg_apple)
        banana.append(avg_banana)
        coconut.append(avg_coconut)
        durian.append(avg_durian)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach to this problem:

```
from collections import defaultdict
C = .......

def average(source):
    data = defaultdict(int)
    for fruit in source:
        data[fruit] += 1
    total = sum([x for x in data.values()])
    for fruit, count in data.items():
        print(f"{fruit}: {count/total}")

def iterate_lines(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield from C[i]

for n in range(1, 21):
    print(n)
    average(iterate_lines(n))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to access the row, make sure you access C[i] before using the count method. Also, the Total should be the row length.

```
C = [['durian', 'durian', 'coconut', 'durian'], ['durian', 'apple', 'durian', 'coconut'], ['coconut', 'durian', 'coconut', 'durian'], ['coconut', 'durian', 'banana', 'durian'], ['banana', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana'], ['coconut', 'durian', 'durian', 'coconut'], ['banana', 'durian', 'banana', 'coconut'], ['coconut', 'banana', 'durian', 'coconut'], ['durian', 'banana', 'coconut', 'durian'], ['durian', 'durian', 'durian', 'banana'], ['banana', 'apple', 'coconut', 'banana'], ['coconut', 'coconut', 'coconut', 'durian'], ['banana', 'coconut', 'durian', 'durian'], ['durian', 'durian', 'durian', 'coconut'], ['durian', 'coconut', 'durian', 'durian'], ['banana', 'apple', 'durian', 'durian'], ['durian', 'banana', 'banana', 'durian'], ['coconut', 'durian', 'coconut', 'coconut'], ['apple', 'coconut', 'durian', 'durian'], ['coconut', 'apple', 'coconut', 'banana']]

for i in C[i]:
    Apple=C[i].count('apple')
    Banana=C[i].count('banana')
    Coconut=C[i].count('coconut')
    Durian=C[i].count('durian')
    Total=len(C[0])
    avg_apple=Apple/Total
    avg_banana=Banana/Total
    avg_coconut=Coconut/Total
    avg_durian=Durian/Total
    avg=[avg_apple,avg_banana,avg_coconut,avg_durian]
    average.append(avg)
    apple.append(avg_apple)
    banana.append(avg_banana)
    coconut.append(avg_coconut)
    durian.append(avg_durian)
    break
```